# Unix - Command line to see users currently running Bash

Tags: unix, command, line

This is my first time learning Unix.

I know that the command line `$ w` allows the user to display the list of users currently running different type of programs or codes on Unix.

Is there a command line that lets you display specific number of users? I'm looking for a command line that can display only the people who are running bash. If that's not possible, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Or [read about the `ps` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html).

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions.

Comment: Thank you falsetru

Answer (score 0):

`w | grep bash` ? – falsetru

Thank you falsetru – yapic